# How to lower RAM consumption in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, memory, ram, yolo, conv-neural-network

**Hello there,**

I am trying to use DarkFlow, a Python implementation of YOLO (which uses Tensorflow as backend), on my Nvidia Jetson Nano to detect objects. I got all the setup and stuff, but it doesn't want to train. I set it to GPU mode and a line in the output says this:

```
Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 897MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: NVIDIA Tegra X1, pci bus id: 0000:00:00.0, compute capability: 5.3)
```

This is the last line it outputs before the training gets "Killed" without any further messages. Because it's a heavy convolutional NN, I think the reason is RAM over-comsumption. Now I only can use this GPU in my Jetson Nano so, does anybody have a suggestion how to lower it or how to solve the problem otherwise?

*Thanks for the answers in advance!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try to decrease `batch_size` to 1 and lower the `width,height` values but would not recommend a training session on `jetson nano`. Its *limited capabilities*(4 GB **shared** RAM) hinders the learning process. To counter the limitations you could try to follow [this](https://www.jetsonhacks.com/2019/04/14/jetson-nano-use-more-memory/) post or [this](https://www.jetsonhacks.com/2019/11/28/jetson-nano-even-more-swap/) one to increase `swap_area` which acts as RAM but still I would recommend using nano only for inference.

*EDIT1*: Also it is known that `Tensorflow` has a tendency to try to allocate all available RAM which makes the process killed by OS. To solve the issue you could use `tf.GPUOptions` to limit `Tensorflow`'s RAM usage.
Example:

```
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.4)
session = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))
```

We have chosen `per_process_gpu_memory_fraction` as 0.4 because it is best practice not to let `Tensorflow` allocate more RAM than half of the available resources.(Also because it is being shared)

Best of luck.